# Why in PHP using Generator::throw omits yielded values after throw

Tags: php, generator, throw

I'm trying to understand why [Generator::throw](http://php.net/manual/en/generator.throw.php) makes caller not to receive values after caught `Exception` in `Generator`.

```
<?php

class moo
{
    public function run()
    {
        $generator = $this->getIterator();
        foreach ($generator as $item) {
            try {
                error_log("PROCESS: {$item}");

                if ($item % 2 === 0) {
                    error_log("throwing InvalidArgumentException $item");
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException($item);
                }
            } catch (Throwable $e) {
                $generator->throw($e);
            }
        }
    }

    private function getIterator()
    {
        foreach (range(1, 6) as $item) {
            try {
                yield $item;

            } catch (Throwable $e) {

                $class = get_class($e);
                error_log("GOT[$class] in generator: {$e->getMessage()}");
            }
        }
    }
}

$m = new moo();
$m->run();
```

the above code prints:

```
PROCESS: 1
PROCESS: 2
throwing InvalidArgumentException 2
GOT[InvalidArgumentException] in generator: 2
PROCESS: 4
throwing InvalidArgumentException 4
GOT[InvalidArgumentException] in generator: 4
PROCESS: 6
throwing InvalidArgumentException 6
GOT[InvalidArgumentException] in generator: 6
```

so values like 3 and 5 are not seen by loop on `run` method

The documentation does not indicate that this is expected behaviour

> Throws an exception into the generator and resumes execution of the
>   generator. The behavior will be the same as if the current yield
>   expression was replaced with a throw $exception statement.

is this is a bug in php?

Comment: Your `GOT[InvalidArgumentException] in generator: 2` lines are happening on the odd iterations.

Comment: @AndyFoster the problem is missing `PROCESS: 3`, `PROCESS: 5`. i.e `run` method is not receiving those values.

Comment: Paul Crovella comment explained well what is happening. as processing value of  `$gen->throw` method may also throw, used `goto` statement to process that return value (`gen8.php`)

https://gist.github.com/glensc/941759de6864e2c8b80e9ca985c00e56#file-gen8-php

however, it had tiny bug when exception happended when generator ended. so added `$gen->valid()` check (`gen9.php`):

https://gist.github.com/glensc/941759de6864e2c8b80e9ca985c00e56#file-gen9-php

i also created wrapper class to make it more transparent for use cases like me. will add to gist it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

As You quote from PHP docs:

> ...The behavior will be the same as if the current **yield expression
>   was replaced with a throw** $exception statement.

This is expected behavior.

Comment: If that is the behavior, shouldn't the output be `PROCESS: 1`, `PROCESS: 3` , `PROCESS: 5`?

https://gist.github.com/glensc/941759de6864e2c8b80e9ca985c00e56

Comment: No. First you get '2' from generator in normal foreach iteration, and then throw exception. And the generator is moved forward to next (3) value by `generator->trow()`. And then next value (4) is received in next foreach iteration.

Answer (score 1):

As [Paul Crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382259/why-in-php-using-generatorthrow-omits-yielded-values-after-throw#comment89737096_51382259) and [Łukasz Jakubek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382259/why-in-php-using-generatorthrow-omits-yielded-values-after-throw#comment89739779_51382709) explained, the value gets "lost" into return value of `$generator->throw()`.

I've created a project, if Generator is wrapped, the `yield` values appear sequential to the yield consumer: https://github.com/glensc/ThrowableGenerator

EDIT: added ::send() wrapper as well: https://github.com/glensc/ThrowableGenerator/releases/tag/1.1.0